# Is there any way to give depth limit as a parameter in Neo4j multi step relationship between nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I want to give depth limit as a parameter for this multi step relationship between nodes.

```
params.put("max",(orderedlist.size())-1);

    String query="match p=((a{name: {name1}})-[:connect*0..{max}]->(b{name: {name2})) return nodes(p) as n";

    result = engine.execute( query,params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parameterize relationship depth. Instead, you can replace the value in your code before executing the query.

Comment: Actually list elements are populated dynamically so that i cant predict the size of the list and replace the value before executing query.

Comment: Just substitute the value that you're assigning to your "max" param anyway- orderedlist.size()-1

Comment: String query="match p=((a{name: {name1}})-[:connect*0..(length(ordered_list)-1)]->(b{name: {name2})) return nodes(p) as n"; its not working....... i dont know any other method..

Comment: String query="match p=((a{name: {name1}})-[:connect*0.." + length(ordered_list)-1 + "]->(b{name: {name2})) return nodes(p) as n";

Comment: oh!! thanks a lot for spending your precious time.Its working...                                  String query="match p=((a{name: {name1}})-[:connect*0.." + (orderedlist.size()-1) + "]->(b{name: {name2})) return nodes(p) as n";   Thanks ...

Comment: welcome, please accept the answer to close this question